# How do I install an older version of Google Chrome?

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome

I'm not to familiar with Ubuntu, but I need to install the previous version because the current one has some bugs.

I went to here and found the version that I wanted: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable

Naturally, I tried to install it with apt-get: 
`sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable=51.0.2704.106-1`

However, after running that command, I received this message and I tried Googling the issue and couldn't find a solution:

```
ubuntu@box533:~$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable=51.0.2704.106-1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '51.0.2704.106-1' for 'google-chrome-stable' was not found
ubuntu@box533:~$
```

How can I install an older version of Google Chrome via command line?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to install older Chrome very easy. I first installed latest Chrome (v64). Then installed older v61 version from here:

https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/artful/universe/base/chromium-browser

with this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra chromium-browser_61.0.3163.100-0ubuntu1.1378_amd64.deb
```

also, make sure to block updates like this:

```
sudo apt-mark hold chromium-browser
```

You just run it as `dkpg -i` on your dist and see if some dep fail.. and if it does, your chance is to list it with `--ignore-depends=` flag and see if it goes through.

I've used this on my `Ubuntu 16.04x64` because on newer versions > v64 you can't use `.dev` for staging for web dev purposes, see details here:

https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

output from cli is:

```
krex@krex-N752VX:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg  -i --ignore-depends=chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra chromium-browser_61.0.3163.100-0ubuntu1.1378_amd64.deb
dpkg: warning: downgrading chromium-browser from 64.0.3282.140-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 to 61.0.3163.100-0ubuntu1.1378
(Reading database ... 686845 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack chromium-browser_61.0.3163.100-0ubuntu1.1378_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chromium-browser (61.0.3163.100-0ubuntu1.1378) over (64.0.3282.140-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up chromium-browser (61.0.3163.100-0ubuntu1.1378) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unless you could grab a copy of the version 51 of Google Chrome. Because Google never allow downloading of older releases and what you found on ubuntuupdates.org is just a reference. They do not host any binary files.

Your best bet is to search in some non-techy friend who doesn't update browsers for years (old grandma's pc can help here too) and see if they have a 51.