# Virtual Host not working as expected when I'm using .dev domain extension

Tags: 16.04, apache2, virtualhost

I'm doing a Laravel project and I need to set up a virtual host `example.dev` in my system. For that I've created a copy of `000-default.conf` and named it as `example.dev.conf` and placed in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. The contents of the file is given below (comments removed):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html/example/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ServerName example.dev
    ServerAlias www.example.dev

    ServerAdmin admin@example.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I've enabled the site using `a2ensite` command and disabled `000-default.conf` using `a2dissite` command. Then it will open my project when I try `localhost` (/var/www/html) in my browser and not `example.dev`. The virtual host `example.dev` always produce "The site can't be reached" error in browsers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've also added the site to the /etc/hosts file:

`172.168.0.1 www.example.dev` (tried without www too).

Comment: have you tried `127.0.0.1 www.example.dev` instead?

Comment: @MD9 Haven't tried that. Can I use `localhost` after that?

Comment: @AnoopS I guess the IP address should be 192.168.0.1 instead of 172.168.0.1

Comment: @MD9 Tried that, same result.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Tried that, same result. But I suppose we can give any ip in that place, right? That will redirect us to the host we provided in there. That's how it works, no?

Comment: You should choice domain extension *different* from `.dev`. Last year Google bought `.dev`, `.foo` and some other domain extensions. Now the redirection to `https://` of these is hard coded in some browsers. Few days ago I read here a nice answer about that, but I can't find it. The proposed duplication should be also helpful.

Comment: @pa4080 changed from `dev` to `example.local`. It also produces same results.

Comment: @AnoopS it has to be your web server's IP address Your browser will try to connect to that IP address if you visit `www.example.dev`, and then your web server will try to find a matching VirtualHost for `www.example.dev`.

Comment: The line in `/etc/hosts` should be `127.0.0.1 localhost example-dev.org www.example-dev.org`, etc... You can use and your LAN IP, but when the network interface is down it shouldn't work. Then use `ServerName example-dev.org` and `ServerAlias www.example-dev.org`.

Comment: Please review this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/941305/566421

Comment: @pa4080 It worked when changed the line in `/etc/hosts` to:

`127.0.0.1 localhost example.local www.example.local`

Now I can access both my localhost and the virtual host. Thank you for your support mate. :)

Comment: I'm glad to help, @AnoopS! **I've retracted my close vote.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First choice domain extension different from `.dev`. Last year Google bought `.dev`, `.foo` and some other domain extensions. Now the redirection to `https://` of these is hard coded in some browsers. More details could be find in [this helpful answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/985300/566421).

Then edit your `/etc/hosts` file in this way (more details could be fund in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/941305/566421)):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost example.local www.example.local
```

Then edit your `<virtual-host>.conf` file in the following way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example.local
    ServerAlias www.example.local
    ServerAdmin admin@example.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/example/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, reload Apache's configuration and try to access `http://example.local`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as I used to name all my test sites .dev -- changing all of my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` config files (and local hosts file) as per pa4080's answer fixed it for me.

Use `a2dissite` to remove the old configs (before you delete the files) and `a2ensite` to enable the new.

Make sure to reload apache with service apache2 reload as well.